# How do you simulate a Rails error flash in jsp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsp, jstl, rails-flash

Is there a jsp/jstl equivalent of this Rails error flash?

```
    <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    <%- end -%>
```

I've been looking for a pre-built solution that is as simple as this Rails idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSTL `c:forEach` to iterate over a `Map<String, String>`. Every iteration gives you a [`Map.Entry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods. Assuming that you've put it in the request scope by key `messages`, here's an example:

```
<dl>
    <c:forEach items="${messages}" var="entry">
        <dt>${entry.key}</dt><dd>${entry.value}</dd>
    </c:forEach>
</dl>
```

---

By the way, JSP/JSTL is not really comparable to the RoR MVC framework. JSP/JSTL is pretty low-level and offers practically no useful abstractions/facilities out of the box to represent a decent MVC approach. You may want to take a look for JSF 2.0 instead. It's the Java EE provided MVC framework. JSP is *just* a view technology. JSTL is *just* a standard flow/function/format taglib. [Here's a JSF 2.0 tutorial](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/).

Comment: Thanks for the JSF link. Someone else told me to look at Sitemesh. Would that be similar to JSF?

Comment: Sitemesh is a templating (layout/decoration/include) framework. It's not a MVC framework. You don't need it in JSF 2.0 as well. JSF 2.0 itself uses Facelets instead of JSP as view technology which in turn already offers pretty awesome templating possibilities. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp/2097732#2097732) to learn more about JSP/Servlet/JSF.